# Dictionary Sort .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dictionary

I'm having a problem how to proper sort a dictonary in **.NET 2.0**. This bit of code is kinda old (2002 or something) and it works, but not the way I want to. Because the **AvailableFlights** Dictionary can be very huge, this sort function can take a lot of time which clients don't have sooo.

Anyone have an idea how to do this, the only way I know is to add an orderby or something, since I was playing in the garden when it was 2002.

**Note:** this is code of an ongoing website, the problem is, my boss want this faster but I can't do huge changes to the project.

The sort function itself works like this: There's a dictionary **AvailableFlight** which contains Flight objects (with the **TotalPrice**). This comes from an external source so pre-filtering isn't an option. The goal to achieve is to have the flights with the lowest **TotalPrice on top**.

**FOR THE PEOPLE** who have no clue what i'm asking, in my project there is a **dictionary** who contains flight objects stored as object with corresponding integer keys. A **flight object** has a property **Totalprice** which need to be sorted **ASC**. This happens with the code I provide, only the time processing this piece of code takes about 30 seconds or more, which is unacceptable. So the question is, how can I improve this so the time processing cuts down.

```
 public void SortFlightResult()
    {
        //bool to check sorting is done or not
        bool blSort = true;
        //bool to stay in while or not
        bool blWhileSort = true;
        while (blWhileSort)
        {
            //check the availableFlights
            foreach (int i in AvailableFlights.Keys)
            {
                foreach (int j in AvailableFlights.Keys)
                {
                    //if id j is greater then id i and price is less then j must be in place of i
                    if ((AvailableFlights[j].TotalPrice < AvailableFlights[i].TotalPrice) && (j > i))
                    {
                        //set temperary AvailableFlight object
                        AvailableFlight avTemp = new AvailableFlight();
                        avTemp = AvailableFlights[i];
                        AvailableFlights[i] = AvailableFlights[j];
                        //keep id of the i (if j.id = 3 and i.id = 2) replace i with j but let id = 2
                        AvailableFlights[i].ID = i;
                        AvailableFlights[j] = avTemp;
                        AvailableFlights[j].ID = j;
                        //set bool fase so we know sort is not done
                        blSort = false;
                        //end both foreach loop so we can start over from the top of availableFlights
                        goto endLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
        endLoop:
            //if true --> availableFlights is sorted set bool while false to quit the function
            if (blSort)
            {
                blWhileSort = false;
            }
            else
            {//set bool sort back to true
                blSort = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

All the bullsh*t aside, thanks to @D Stanley for his usefull comment.
I Changed to algorithm to a **Heap sort** and the time processing the sort cuts down from about **30 seconds** to **400 miliseconds**, really glad with that!

For the people who are interested in the heap sort code:

**Heapsort**

```
    public void HeapSort()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        //Build Max-Heap
        Dictionary<int, AvailableFlight> input = AvailableFlights;
        int heapSize = input.Keys.Count;

        for (int p = (heapSize -1) /2; p >= 0; p--)
        {
            MaxHeapify(AvailableFlights, heapSize, p);
        }
        for (int i = AvailableFlights.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            //Swap
            AvailableFlight temp = input[i];
            input[i] = input[0];
            input[0] = temp;

            heapSize--;
            MaxHeapify(AvailableFlights, heapSize, 0);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("SortFlightResult 2: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

**MaxHeapify**

```
    private static void MaxHeapify(Dictionary<int, AvailableFlight> input, int heapSize, int index)
    {
        int left = (index + 1) * 2 - 1;
        int right = (index + 1) * 2;
        int largest = 0;

        if (left < heapSize && input[left].TotalPrice > input[index].TotalPrice)
        {
            largest = left;
        }
        else
        {
            largest = index;
        }

        if (right < heapSize && input[right].TotalPrice > input[largest].TotalPrice)
        {
            largest = right;
        }
        if (largest != index)
        {
            AvailableFlight temp = input[index];
            input[index] = input[largest];
            input[largest] = temp;

            MaxHeapify(input, heapSize, largest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted - if you want to have a list of items and be able to reorder the items use a `List` instead of a `Dictionary`

Comment: [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes. SortedDictionary.

Comment: @Sinatr Even with a sorted dictionary the code is _reorganizing the items_.  There's no indication that the benefits of a Dictionary are utilized here.

Comment: The mere fact that you use `goto` indicates that you are not using the right procedure or data structure.

Comment: Like I said, this is code from 2002, made by someone who called himself a programmer back in the day, now I get the silly task of speeding up this bit of code, but I just don't have the know-how, the skills or the analytical skills to improve this in a quick fix. This is important, no huge changes are allowed

Comment: @derloopkat linq is not available in .net 2.0

Comment: Would changing the sort algorithm be considered a "huge change"? You might do some research on [sorting algorithms](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) to see if a different algorithm may be faster depending on what your starting data is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have something like this `AvailableFlight` class:

```
public class AvailableFlight
{
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    // ... more properties
}
```

You can create a class implementing `IComparer<AvailableFlight>` like this:

```
public class FlightByPriceComparer : IComparer<AvailableFlight>
{
    public int Compare(AvailableFlight x, AvailableFlight y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return ReferenceEquals(y, null) ? 0 : -1;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return 1;
        return x.TotalPrice.CompareTo(y.TotalPrice);
    }
}
```

And use this to sort a `List<AvailableFlight>` of your dictionary's values:

```
Dictionary<int, AvailableFlight> AvailableFlights = ... // whereever you got them from
List<AvailableFlight> sortedFlights = new List<AvailableFlight>(AvailableFlights.Values);
sortedFlights.Sort(new FlightByPriceComparer());
```

This should be faster than your bubble sort, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort) it uses these sort algorithms:

> This method uses System.Array.Sort, which uses the QuickSort algorithm. This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.
>
> On average, this method is an O(n log n) operation, where n is Count; in the worst case it is an O(n ^ 2) operation.

---

Note that it's not possible to *sort a dictionary by its values*, there is a `SortedDictionary` but that is only sorted by its `Keys`.

Comment: If it comes out of a regular Dictionary it's likely to be unsorted anyway. QuickSort is pretty much the fastest you will get without parallelizing everything (which likely counts as a big change) - so I think this is the best answer to the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use System.Linq to make it easy and clear for reading:

```
AvailableFlights = AvailableFlights.OrderBy(x => x.Value.TotalPrice).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: LINQ is not available in .NET2.0, so this won't even compile in OP's code.

Comment: uuups, didn't look at the prerequisites, sorry. So the sorting by List or Array is the only choise!